# Two Factor Authentication for GUI Privilege Elevation prompt on Catalina

Tags: catalina, root, two-factor-authentication

How can I set up two factor authentication for the privilege elevation prompts in macos, e.g System Preferences -> Security & Privacy ->  in bottom left corner.

If smart card is not possible (why? and) what can I use instead? Google-Authenticator OTP? Yubico OTP? Anything else?

---

I am attempting to set up Two FA for macos Catalina. I need twofa for the following:

- Login, Screensaver, `sudo`, and `su`. Already working. (via smart card)
- **Privilege elevation ( icon).** *Not working*.
- I do not need 2fa for FileVault FDE, which I believe is impossible anyways.

I followed [these](https://support.yubico.com/support/solutions/articles/15000010854-macos-native-smart-card-support-for-logon-with-windows-server#Known_Issues8b52lb) Smart Card instructions, and did not realize until the end that it says:

> When attempting to make changes under System Preferences by clicking the padlock, you will need to use your username and password for authentication; smart cards are not supported for authentication in this case (this is a limitation of macOS).

However, [this](https://randomoracle.wordpress.com/2015/02/16/smart-card-logon-for-os-x-part-iv/) article from Feb 2015 (Yosemite?) says:

> In addition to the login screen and screen-saver, elevation prompts for sensitive operations will also work with smart-cards

So did this used to be possible, but isn't anymore? Or is it only the yubico method that can't do smart card for privilege elevation? Or was this never possible, and the second article is just wrong/unclear?

I'm looking for any form of two fa, not just smart card specifically.